# Custom Dialog Window/Pop up window keeps rejecting button input?? Android Studio

Tags: android

So I created a pop-up dialog window to serve as the tutorial for the user, I decided to run tests on it since it was working well but saw that when you added an active button to it, it would not work. Each time I pressed the button that brings up the tutorial(which worked before the addition of the button code), the addition I made with the button taking the user to another part now renders that button inactive and instead takes the user back to the start screen when the tutorial button is pressed.

This is the code I used for it:

```
package com.example.rockpaperscissors;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

import static com.example.rockpaperscissors.R.id.tutorialButton;

public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button tutorialButton, playGameButton, testbutton;
    Dialog tutorial_popup;
         


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tutorial_popup = new Dialog(this);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        playGameButton = findViewById(R.id.playGameButton);
        tutorialButton = findViewById(R.id.tutorialButton);
        testbutton = findViewById(R.id.testbutton);
        tutorial_popup = new Dialog(this);


        playGameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainGame.class));
            }
        });

        tutorialButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tutorial_popup.setContentView(R.layout.tutorial_popup);

                tutorial_popup.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                tutorial_popup.show();
                testbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainGame.class));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, there's another setOnClickListener within the tutorial which is basically supposed to take the user to another class/activity when pressed on. However, it does not do it and instead just ignores it, showing that there is an error.

```
tutorialButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tutorial_popup.setContentView(R.layout.tutorial_popup);

                tutorial_popup.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                tutorial_popup.show();
                testbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainGame.class));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Is there something I missed when doing this? Please let me know how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to this answer, being that there was actually no need to add a buttonListener to the pop-up dialog as not only was it unnecessary, but it was also breaking the code. With how pop-up dialogs work in Android Studio, I realised through watching videos that you are able to click off of it without needing an "X" button or whatsoever, so I removed the buttonListener and tried again. Safe to say it ran perfectly this time with no problems whatsoever.

```
tutorialButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tutorial_popup.setContentView(R.layout.tutorial_popup);
                tutorial_popup.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                tutorial_popup.show();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the onclick on the button before showing the pop up

`testbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) {startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainGame.class));}});  tutorial_popup.show();`

Comment: did that and it still does not work for some reason